# Как удалить битый каталог

Tags: linux, mount

Мой комп (OS : Fedora 35), во время загрузки выполняет монтирование сетевого ресурса на папку */mnt/nas4free*. До сегодняшнего дня всё было прекрасно.

Но сегодня сервер *nas4free* почему-то перестал монтироваться. Посмотрел каталог */etc* и увидел, что каталог каким-то образом разрушен:

```
$ ls -l /mnt
ls: невозможно получить доступ к '/mnt/nas4free': Ресурс временно недоступен
итого 24
drwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  4096 фев 20 22:05 disk_c
drwxrwxr-x. 1 root users 4096 фев 12 21:08 disk_d
d?????????? ? ?    ?        ?            ? nas4free
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root  4096 дек  7  2020 sdd
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root  4096 апр 22  2021 sysimage
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root  4096 апр 22  2021 sysroot
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root  4096 янв 27 14:02 T.sonic
```

Я попытался его удалить, но ничего не получилось:

```
$ sudo rmdir /mnt/nas4free
[sudo] пароль для lary: 
rmdir: не удалось удалить '/mnt/nas4free': Устройство или ресурс занято
```

Я пытался удалить его разными способами. Но всегда одна ошибка: Устройство или ресурс занято

Что можно сделать в такой ситуации ?

Comment: нум... `fsck` прогнать для начала...

Comment: История оказалась совсем интересной! :-) После перезагрузки каталог /mnt/nas4free выглядит вполне нормальным. На сетевой ресурс можно зайти и работать с файлами. Однако, после того, как я запускаю VPN-клиента Mullvad VPN, ссылка начинает выглядеть битой и работать с ресурсом невозможно. 

Отключаю VPN-клиента, работоспособность восстанавливается. Что-то я не могу представить, как VPN связан с монтирование шары по SMB протоколу ?!

Comment: Ну впн перекрывает своими сетевыми настройками системные?

Answer (score 0):

Всё оказалось очень просто. В настройках *Mullvad VPN* есть пункт "Разрешить работу с локальной сетью". Я взвёл этот переключатель и всё прекрасно заработало!